# R - Summing over a row for specific columns using a list

Tags: r, dataframe, sum

My goal is to sum certain columns of my dataframe and input that sum into a new column.

Suppose I have the following data.frame:

```
df <- data.frame(names=c("a","b","c","d","e","f"),
                 wb01=c(1,1,0,1,1,0),
                 wb02=c(0,0,0,0,1,1),
                 wb03=c(0,0,1,1,1,1),
                 wb04=c(1,1,0,1,1,1),
                 wb05=c(1,0,1,0,0,1),
                 wb06=c(1,1,1,1,1,1)) 

rownames(df) <- df$names

  wb01 wb02 wb03 wb04 wb05 wb06
a  1    0    0    1    1    1
b  1    0    0    1    0    1
c  0    0    1    0    1    1
d  1    0    1    1    0    1
e  1    1    1    1    0    1
f  0    1    1    1    1    1
```

I would like to select what columns are to be summed by using a vector that will contain the names of the columns to be sum. (My real dataframe and the number of columns I will be choosing is quite large and not in bunched together, ie/ I can't just choose columns 3-5, nor do I want to type each column since it would be over 2k...)

But back to the example, here are the columns I'd like to sum:

```
genelist <- c(wb02, wb03, wb06)
```

So the results would look like this:

```
  wb01 wb02 wb03 wb04 wb05 wb06 sum_genelist
a  1    0    0    1    1    1         1
b  1    0    0    1    0    1         1
c  0    0    1    0    1    1         2
d  1    0    1    1    0    1         3
e  1    1    1    1    0    1         3
f  0    1    1    1    1    1         3
```

Thanks for any help or tips!

Comment: For the columns mentioned, is there any pattern in the names?

Comment: I posted the data used.  It is working for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rowSums`

```
df$sum_genelist <- rowSums(df[intersect(genelist, names(df))], na.rm = TRUE)
df
#  names wb01 wb02 wb03 wb04 wb05 wb06 sum_genelist
#a     a    1    0    0    1    1    1            1
#b     b    1    0    0    1    0    1            1
#c     c    0    0    1    0    1    1            2
#d     d    1    0    1    1    0    1            2
#e     e    1    1    1    1    0    1            3
#f     f    0    1    1    1    1    1            3
```

where

```
genelist <- c('wb02', 'wb03', 'wb06')
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(names = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), wb01 = c(1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 0), wb02 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), wb03 = c(0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1), wb04 = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), wb05 = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
1), wb06 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c("a", "b", "c", 
"d", "e", "f"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks I tried that and get this error:
Error in `[.data.frame`(df, genelist) : undefined columns selected

Which now makes me think there is something in my genelist that is not in a column in my dataframe... (In my large, real df not this example.)

Comment: @LauraChipman this error can happen only when the `genelist` have some names that are not in the orignal data.  Try `rowSums(df[intersect(genelist, names(df))])`

Comment: @LauraChipman what i meant is that you can replicate the same error on default dataset `mtcars` `mtcars[c('ab', 'cd')]#
Error in `[.data.frame`(mtcars, c("ab", "cd")) : 
  undefined columns selected`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `any_of` to `select` only those columns that are present in your data.

```
genelist <- c('wb02', 'wb03', 'wb06', 'a')
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(sum_genelist = rowSums(select(., any_of(genelist))))

#  names wb01 wb02 wb03 wb04 wb05 wb06 sum_genelist
#1     a    1    0    0    1    1    1            1
#2     b    1    0    0    1    0    1            1
#3     c    0    0    1    0    1    1            2
#4     d    1    0    1    1    0    1            2
#5     e    1    1    1    1    0    1            3
#6     f    0    1    1    1    1    1            3
```